# Change index.html in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am building a new website on wordpress, I chose my theme but I can't visualize anything because it always show "Page under construction". I found the file index.html in the cPanel:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Under Construction - [Ooredoo.tn]</title> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <style> body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; } h1 { font-size: 50px; } body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; } article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; } a { color: #dc8100; text-decoration: none; } a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; } </style> </head> <body> <article> <h1>Under Construction.</h1> <p>Website currently under constrcution</p> <p>We apologize for any inconvenience.</p> <p>&mdash; <a href="mailto:[webmaster@ooredoo.tn]"></a></p> </article> </body> </html>
```

I activated a wordpress theme but it seems that my page doesn't take the theme appearance.

Do you have an idea how I can fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you can access the `wp-admin`?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache. My guess is that your browser cached that placeholder index.html of your hoster. You can also delete this index.html - you won't need it any longer.

Comment: Wordpress uses index.php to control the website, not index.html. What’s happening is that the hosting is giving precedence to the index.html and showing it instead of the index.php. You can delete index.html  (or just rename it if you don’t want to delete it)

Comment: index.html in WordPress???  WordPress websites are built using PHP, not HTML.